# Do we need a canonical ransomware question?

Tags: discussion, canonical

Do we need a canonical question about how to deal with ransomware, so that questions like [this](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225080/ransomware-encrypted-my-files-and-gave-them-a-kodc-extension) could be marked as a duplicate instead of closed as off topic?

An answer could consist of something along the lines of:

- You should keep backups. Restore if you have them.
- Don't pay.
- Check these sites out to see if your specific strain of malware can be decrypted.

Is this a good idea? Are there already a question out there that might fit the bill?

Comment: https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now and add a ransomware section?

Comment: @schroeder I was thinking that question was already to broad as it is, and it feels a bit weird sneaking more questions in years after most answers were posted. But an answer to a new question should probably link to it.

Comment: I'd just add a ransomware section to the top answer.

Comment: I agree with Anders though, when I clicked the link and saw the question I also thought it was rather broad to begin with. Making a canonical question sounds good to me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

**EDIT:** The question is now asked: [Help! Ransomware encrypted my files. What do I do now?](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/225873/help-ransomware-encrypted-my-files-what-do-i-do-now)

Since there hasn't been a lot of protest, I will go ahead and post a question unless there is some more objection. Here's a draft of the question, short but sweet:

> ## Help! Ransomware encrypted my files. What do I do now?
>
> I just discovered that my files has been encrypted by ransomware.
>
> - Can I get my files back? How?
> - Should I pay the ransom?
> - What should I do so that this never happens again?

I'm setting up for an answer along the lines of:

- Restore backups after [nuking form orbit](https://security.stackexchange.com/questions/138606/help-my-home-pc-has-been-infected-by-a-virus-what-do-i-do-now). Or check a list and see if you are lucky.
- Probably not.
- Keep backups.

Feedback is welcome.